# SOQL Query for Parent to child traversal and fetch child id

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a soql join query like below where Case is the parent and Return__c has a lookup relationship to case.

```
              Select ID, CaseNumber, Contact.Salutation ,Contact.Name, 
             (Select  Id, Name,Return_Status__c from Return__c where
              Return_Status__c  = 'Pending') from case limit 20
```

Now I have a map of structure

```
              Map<Id,Id> structure where key = Return__c object's record id and value = Case object's record id.
```

Please suggest the best way to populate the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly do your SOQL on the Return__c child object and get the parent case fields directly from that.

```
Map<Id,Return__c> returnsMap = new Map<Id,Return__c>([Select  Id, Name,Return_Status__c, Case__c, Case__r.CaseNumber, Case__r.Contact.Salutation ,Case__r.Contact.Name 
from Return__c where Return_Status__c  = 'Pending' limit 20]);
```

then you can use `returnsMap.get(yourReturnRecordId)` to get the complete return__c record and then access the fields you are interested including the parent case fields..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your SOQL query if you want to put Ids into map, following script will work for you.

Check the relationship name before executing the query as it must not be `Return__c`, instead `Returns__r`

```
Map<Id, Id> returnId = new Map<Id, Id>();

for(Case caseObj:[Select ID, CaseNumber, Contact.Salutation ,Contact.Name, 
                         (Select  Id, Name,Return_Status__c from Returns__r where
                          Return_Status__c  = 'Pending') 
                          FROM Case limit 20])
{
       for(Return_Status__c rs:caseObj.Returns__r)
        {
            returnId.put(rs.Id, caseObj.Id);
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks..I know this will work..But I am trying to avoid nested for loop.